# Local rotate SCNNode SceneKit within its middle point

Tags: swift, 3d, scenekit, scnnode

I have to `localRotate` once a node within it's z axis and it's 3D **center** (middle point of the node)

Then I should move the node to a new global camera position.  The issue is when apply a movement to x axis the localTranslate should move the node along the global camera axe not node axe.

How can I rotate the node within its middle point then translate as a global object along global x axes?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a code writing service. What you have tried?

Comment: Update your question with code don't add it on comment.

Comment: It should be clear for you if read the question much careful and have experience with SceneKit

Comment: Have you tried to create an empty node as a parent, rotate the object, but move the parent? That way the coordinate system of the node you want to move does not change based on the rotation. Otherwise, use the `pivot` property.

Comment: That way is working :)